# JQuery AJAX post - how to send extra form variables?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using ajax for the first time and have hit a bit of a brick wall.

I've created a single big function with lots of smaller functions inside it which handles all ajax requests. I'm passing a POST variable to tell it which function to process the request with.

For example

```
if(_is_ajax()) {
  if($_POST['save_company']) {
  // Do stuff here
  }
}
```

However, I don't know how to use jQuery ajax functions in a way where I can set the post variable AND pass serialized data.

here's my code:

```
var values = $("#edit_company").serialize();
$.post("/admin/companies", { 'save_company' : true } ,
    function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }, "json")
```

`'save_company' : true` sets the post variable, but where do I include `values`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something similar to this:

```
var frm_data = $("#form1_id").serialize();

 $.ajax(
 {
 type: "POST",
 url: "url.php",
 data: frm_data,
 cache: false,

 success: function(response)
 {
   alert(response);
 }
  });
```

Comment: @Sarfraz's serialized answer is probably closer to what you were looking for, you would simply need to add a hidden input field for **save_company** in the form.

Comment: @cballou: that will be fine :)

Comment: Silly me.. - I was trying to make it too complex in my head.. a simple hidden input field.. durr

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

```
$.post("/admin/companies", { 'save_company' : 'value1', var2: 'value2', var3: true }, callbackFcn);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your form is #edit_company then:

```
 $.post("/admin/companies", $("#edit_company").serialize() ,
    function(data){
            console.log(data);
    }, "json");
```

Should send all the form data.